# Firebase sign in and register methods not working on Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, promise, next.js

I am using the Material-UI Devias Kit Pro Next.js template that uses Firebase for authentication. Neither the `signInWithEmailAndPassword` nor the `registerWithEmailAndPassword` methods work. I could really use some help or tips for debugging this.

My login form calls the handleSubmit method when the user clicks "login" which calls the Firebase `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method. The app correctly routes to the return URL after the login button is clicked, but the app is not authenticated.

Also assume all the Firebase configs are setup correctly.

firebase-login.tsx

```
      <form
        noValidate
        onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}
      >
        
        <TextField
            ...
        />
      
        <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
          <Button
            disabled={formik.isSubmitting}
            fullWidth
            size="large"
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
          >
            Log In
          </Button>
        </Box>
   
      </form>
```

firebase-login.tsx

```
const { signInWithEmailAndPassword } = useAuth();

const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      ...
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      ...
    }),
    onSubmit: async (values, helpers): Promise<void> => {
      try {
        await signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password);

        if (isMounted()) {
          const returnUrl = (router.query.returnUrl as string | undefined) || '/';
          router.push(returnUrl).catch(console.error);
        }
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);

        if (isMounted()) {
          helpers.setStatus({ success: false });
          helpers.setErrors({ submit: err.message });
          helpers.setSubmitting(false);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

use-auth.ts

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../contexts/firebase-auth-context';

export const useAuth = () => useContext(AuthContext) as any;
```

firebase-auth-context.tsx

```
const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);

interface State {
  isInitialized: boolean;
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  user: User | null;
}

export interface AuthContextValue extends State {
  platform: 'Firebase';
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword: (
    email: string,
    password: string
  ) => Promise<any>;
  signInWithEmailAndPassword: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<any>;
  signInWithGoogle: () => Promise<any>;
  logout: () => Promise<void>;
}

interface AuthProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

enum ActionType {
  AUTH_STATE_CHANGED = 'AUTH_STATE_CHANGED'
}

type AuthStateChangedAction = {
  type: ActionType.AUTH_STATE_CHANGED;
  payload: {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;
    user: User | null;
  };
};

type Action = AuthStateChangedAction;

const initialState: State = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  isInitialized: false,
  user: null
};

const reducer = (state: State, action: Action): State => {
  if (action.type === 'AUTH_STATE_CHANGED') {
    const { isAuthenticated, user } = action.payload;

    return {
      ...state,
      isAuthenticated,
      isInitialized: true,
      user
    };
  }

  return state;
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextValue>({
  ...initialState,
  platform: 'Firebase',
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword: () => Promise.resolve(),
  signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => Promise.resolve(),
  signInWithGoogle: () => Promise.resolve(),
  logout: () => Promise.resolve()
});

export const AuthProvider: FC<AuthProviderProps> = (props) => {
  const { children } = props;
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

  useEffect(() => onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      // Here you should extract the complete user profile to make it available in your entire app.
      // The auth state only provides basic information.
      dispatch({
        type: ActionType.AUTH_STATE_CHANGED,
        payload: {
          isAuthenticated: true,
          user: {
            id: user.uid,
            avatar: user.photoURL || undefined,
            email: user.email || 'anika.visser@devias.io',
            name: 'Anika Visser',
            plan: 'Premium',
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: ActionType.AUTH_STATE_CHANGED,
        payload: {
          isAuthenticated: false,
          user: null
        }
      });
    }
  }), [dispatch]);

  const _signInWithEmailAndPassword = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<void> => {
    await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
  };

  const signInWithGoogle = async (): Promise<void> => {
    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
  };

  const _createUserWithEmailAndPassword = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<void> => {
    await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  const logout = async (): Promise<void> => {
    await signOut(auth);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        ...state,
        platform: 'Firebase',
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword: _createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
        signInWithEmailAndPassword: _signInWithEmailAndPassword,
        signInWithGoogle,
        logout
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

AuthProvider.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired
};

export const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer;
```

Comment: Can you try logging the result of sign in? `const result = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(values.email, values.password);` and then share the output ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj the result is `undefined`.

Comment: @Dharmaraj also when I add a log statement inside the `_signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method, it isn't getting hit.